# Django value error on multiple form on one page

Tags: django

I have a form on one template that every time i hit the submit button , i get redirected to a page that throws a value error. I've tried searching online for help but had no luck, the other form works perfectly fine on the template it's just the document form. I've searched online for handling more then one form on one template and came across, a set of code that was sort of structured like this. But for some odd reason i can't get it to work, i event tried to write a seperate view for my second form with no luck. I'm still pretty new to django.

```
def modify_land(request, pk):
    # Query Sets
    land = get_object_or_404(Land, pk=pk)
    land_use_types = LandType.objects.all()
    countries = Country.objects.all()
    province_states = ProvinceState.objects.all()
    counties = County.objects.all()
    lld_types = LLDType.objects.all()
    land_owners = LandOwner.objects.all()
    tenants = Tenant.objects.all()
    documents = Document.objects.all()
    document_types = DocumentType.objects.all()
    document_statuses = DocumentStatus.objects.all()
    partners = Partner.objects.all()
    events = Event.objects.all()
    # Forms
    doc_form = DocumentForm()
    # Modify Land
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = LandForm(request.POST, instance=land)
        if form.is_valid():
            land = form.save(commit=False)
            land.creator = request.user
            land.modified_date = timezone.now()
            land.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Object has Been Modified')
            return redirect(lands_home)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Object Has Not Been Modified')
    else:
        form = LandForm(instance=land)
    # Create Relationship to Document
    if request.method == "POST" and 'land_rel_doc' in request.POST:
        doc_form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if doc_form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.creator = request.user
            document.created_date = timezone.now()
            document.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Object Has Been Created')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Object Has Not Been Created')
    else:
        doc_form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request,
                  'process_lands_management/modify_land.html',
                  {'form': form,
                   'doc_form': doc_form,
                   'land': land,
                   'land_use_types': land_use_types,
                   'countries': countries,
                   'province_states': province_states,
                   'counties': counties,
                   'lld_types': lld_types,
                   'land_owners': land_owners,
                   'tenants': tenants,
                   'documents': documents,
                   'document_types': document_types,
                   'document_statuses': document_statuses,
                   'partners': partners,
                   'events': events,
                   'title': 'Modify Land'})
```

Error:

```
Internal Server Error: /process_lands_management/modify_land/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/.virtualenvs/django_imax/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 39, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/python/.virtualenvs/django_imax/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 249, in _legacy_get_response
    response = self._get_response(request)
  File "/home/python/.virtualenvs/django_imax/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/python/.virtualenvs/django_imax/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/python/python/django_imax/django_imax/process_lands_management/views.py", line 114, in modify_land
    document = form.save(commit=False)
  File "/home/python/.virtualenvs/django_imax/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 443, in save
    'created' if self.instance._state.adding else 'changed',
ValueError: The Land could not be changed because the data didn't validate.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To receive better answers you should specify what is the error you get and what have you tried so far, if in doubt see the [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section

Comment: Thanks, sorry forgot to add the error at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change line `document = form.save(commit=False)` to `document = doc_form.save(commit=False)`

Comment: Thanks so much, I totally missed that little piece.